# Can't run a background worker on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure ElasticBeanstalk to run a Flask-RQ2 worker inside of a Docker container. So, I created the following config under .ebextensions directory:

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_workers.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #nohup docker exec $(docker ps | grep $(docker images -q aws_beanstalk/current-app) | awk '{print $1}') flask rq worker > /dev/null 2>&1 &

container_commands:
    001-run-worker:
    leader_only: true
    command: "sed -i -e 's/#//' /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_workers.sh"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

After deployment it's not able to see the worker is running.

```
$ docker exec $(docker ps | grep $(docker images -q aws_beanstalk/current-app) | awk '{print $1}') flask rq info
default      | 0
1 queues, 0 jobs total

0 workers, 1 queues

Updated: 2019-01-31 19:44:13.182584
```

And calling the worker command under SSH works well:

```
$ docker exec $(docker ps | grep $(docker images -q aws_beanstalk/current-app) | awk '{print $1}') flask rq worker
[2019-01-31 19:46:04,618] INFO in worker: RQ worker 'rq:worker:72892ec44d9b.66' started, version 0.13.0
[2019-01-31 19:46:04,620] INFO in worker: *** Listening on default...
[2019-01-31 19:46:04,621] INFO in worker: Cleaning registries for queue: default
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPD**

Today re-deployed the app and the worker seems to be started.

```
$ docker exec $(docker ps | grep $(docker images -q aws_beanstalk/current-app) | awk '{print $1}') flask rq info
default      | 0
1 queues, 0 jobs total

f89e0061ba39.13 idle: default
1 workers, 1 queues

Updated: 2019-02-01 08:24:40.154956
```

Comment: where is your cron.yaml ?

Comment: I need to run worker on a web server environment (not worker environment).
The idea is to run a worker on a single instance (**leader_only**).